# Dangling Class on Viewmodel DisplayName not being used on LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to get a display name for an inner class on my view model to be shown on labelfor.

However it only ever displays "Name" for DetailsTab.PrimaryContact.Name
I've tried changing the attribute to Display(Name = "") also but that doesn't seem to work.Everywhere I look they say that this should be working but i just cannot get it to work. Have I missed something?

Question: How do I get my inner property to use the displayname on the labelfor

```
public class CustomerDetailsData
    {
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Tenant ID")]
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DetailsData DetailsTab { get; set; }
        public class DetailsData
        {
            [DisplayName("Industry")]
            [StringLength(250)]
            public string Industry { get; set; }
            [DisplayName("Team Count")]
            [StringLength(250)]
            public string TeamCount { get; set; }
            public PrimaryContactData PrimaryContact { get; set; }

            public class PrimaryContactData
            {
                [DisplayName("Primary Contact Name")]
                public string Name { get; set; }
                [DisplayName("Primary Contact Email")]
                public string Email { get; set;}
                [DisplayName("Primary Contact Phone")]
                public string Phone { get; set;}
            }
        }
    }



<div class="row">
     <div class="large-2 columns">
          @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DetailsTab.PrimaryContact.Name)
     </div>
     <div class="large-10 columns">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DetailsTab.PrimaryContact.Name)
     </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Just to make a test, could you change the `Name` property in your `PrimaryContactData` to something else, like `PrimaryContactName` and test it again?

Comment: Hi @Alisson I did the above and it returned "Primary Contact Name" so assuming its spacing by capitalisation. Ideally I would be able to use a LabelFor and DisplayName as i feel theres no need to declare PrimaryContact in the property name again as ive separated it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if my project wasn't building properly, I did a rebuild and it started to pick up  my DisplayName

Comment: I think this wasn't the reason. It looks `DisplayNameFor()` and other of these `HTML` helper methods relies in the `Model` when inspecting properties. Actually, it looks since the property name (**Name**) was coincidentally existed in the `Model` (which is `CustomerDetailsData`), the helper was considering that property from the model, instead of the child class.

Comment: I did rename the property back to Name and then tested again and it works fine with the property as Name. Restarting visual studio fixed it for me. Thanks for the responses; wouldn't have tried if you hadnt sebt me down that chsin of thought.

Comment: Hmmm, that's interesting. I never had this kind of trouble, but it's good to know what you had to do.